Spanish Characters erratically being saved in MongoDB as non utf-8 characters (�)
Seemingly all of a sudden, we started noticing that non traditional characters like "ñ" "¿" or "é" are being saved as a non utf-8 character "�".
We reverted to previous versions of both our front and back end and the issue is still there, apparently dismissing issues with new code commits.
If we run locally, there is no problem whatsoever.
When we deploy a version, it seems to work for a while, until we refresh or try with a different browser, at which point it fails and seemingly corrupts something within the flow and fails thenceforth.
Our instantiation, and queries are pretty straight forward:
mongoose
    .set("strictQuery", false)
    .connect(config.MONGO_DB_URI, {
      enableUtf8Validation: true, // We initially didn't have this and the back end crashed, now it doesn't but it simply show the corrupted characters.
    })

export const PostDBModel = mongoose.model<PostDB>("Post", postSchema);

const updatePost = await PostDBModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: _id },
      { title, content, category, tags },
      { new: true }
    );

Our stack:

React.js in the front end, with a graphQL integration using both Apollo client and server to communicate front and back
Node.js in the back end with Typescript
MongoDB as DBMS and mongoose as ODM

What could be a potential reason for this?

� is a UTF-8 character, specifically its codepoint is U+FFFD

@DPenner1 it shows as that, but the error we get is that it was not saved as a UTF-8 character. I imagine that character is a representation of a broken character

This is caused by a bug in Node 22.7.0. You will need to downgrade, preferably to the LTS version 20.x rather than 22.x.
See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/54543
